# New Rails app error - HOME environment variable must be set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have installed RoR from http://railsinstaller.org/ru-RU
My system is Windows 7 x86
When i try to create new app using "rails new test_app" i get this error:

> /D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rbreadline.rb:1097:in
>   `': HOME environment variable (or HOMEDRIVE and
>   HOMEPATH) must be set and point to a directory (RuntimeError)

How can I fix this? I already found a topic with the same problem, but it didn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced with this problem, using russian version of Windows 7 x86. Command "env | grep HOME" showed me bad route with unusual characters for HOME and HOMEPATH. Reassigning HOME with command "set HOME=your_real_folder_location" solved the problem.